# Importing modules from deeply nested directory structures

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code

Importing a module that is not in or around the same folder is quite a nuisance. You have to keep counting the '../'. Like in the example below:

```
import {AnswersService, AddAnswerModel, Answer} from '../../../../../../../BackendServices/AnswersService';
```

By modifying my System.config to the example below, I can get around having all of these '../' and the code works perfectly on the browser.

```
System.config({
        packages: { 
            'app': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
            'rxjs': { defaultExtension: 'js' }
        },
        paths: {
            'rxjs/*': 'node_modules/rxjs/*',
            'BackendServices/*': 'app/BackendServices/*'
        }
    });
```

It reduces the import statement to the manageable command below.

```
import {AnswersService, AddAnswerModel, Answer} from 'BackendServices/AnswersService';
```

But the problem with this approach is that I lose intellisense in Visual Studio Code. I am not sure if this is a typescript problem, a visual studio code problem, or something else.

Does anyone know how to get this working without losing intellisense?

Comment: Why do you have such incredibly deep directory structure? Keep your whole tree 2-3 level deep.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual Studio can only resolve relative paths and modules located in node_modules like `angular2/*` or `rxjs/*`.

It is the TypeScript default moduleResolution ( node ) .. you can change it in tsconfig.json with 'classic' .. but VS Code will no longer recognize node modules.

The problem is discussed in this ticket https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5039

There are many proposals .. but nothing is implemented yet.

Comment: For the OP, maybe the solution is to package the app resources in a private repo with the requisite npm metadata so that the app is installed into the dev environment with npm?

Comment: you can package some parts of your application ( backed connectors for example) in a separate npm module .. and make a .d.ts file that exports the modules. But it's not practical.

I have checked the code source of Angular2. They don't use '../..' path resolution. 

In the tsconfig.json they have  "moduleResolution": "classic" ( default value is "node" ) 

I tried it .. it works .. but the node modules are no longer recongnized. :(

Comment: Thanks guys for the reply. I guess we'll have to wait until this problem is tackled in the future. Packaging the application parts into private rep doesn't seem feasible for my current project. So I guess I'll have to keep a flat component directory for now. And refactor the application in the future once they tackle this problem. Thanks for the all the help!

Answer (score 6):

You can copy a pattern that is implemented by the `angular-cli` by exporting every component you want available elsewhere through an `index.ts` at the directory level. This way you can expose nested components at a higher level.

Here's an example:

```
parent
├── child
│   ├── child.component.ts
│   └── index.ts
├── parent.component.ts
└── index.ts
```

Inside `child/index.ts` simply export relevant components.

```
export { ChildComponent } from './child.component';
```

Then `parent/index.ts` can continue the export chain.

```
export { ParentComponent } from './parent.component';
export { ChildComponent } from './child';
```

NOTE: Notice how the above is not referencing the `child.component` file, but the `child` **directory** instead!

The `child` directory's `index.ts` surfaces these components via the exports in `index.ts`. This can be done for however deeply nested your components are.

Lastly, if another component outside of `parent/` wanted to consume anything inside of `parent/`, it could be referenced easily at the topmost level.

```
import { ParentComponent, ChildComponent } from './parent';
```