# Ionic 2: tsconfig.json modifications not working in order to prevent long relative paths

Tags: typescript, ionic2

I started an ionic 2 project and one of the few things I don't like is the relative paths. I read some documentation from typescript and I modified the tsconfig.json file, and seems like the modifications I do are not taking any effect in the ionic app (but are working in typescript).

I learned how typescript works from the documentation: http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html

I validated that my changes to tsconfig.json are correct since calling "tsc --traceResolution" tells me the resolution is working. But once I launch the ionic app I get the "Cannot find module" error.

**Example**

In order to reproduce the issue, create a brand new ionic 2 project, modify tsconfig.json by adding the following to compilerOptions:

```
"baseUrl": "./src",
```

Then create the file src/foo.ts with the contents:

```
export class Foo {}
```

finally add the following to app.module.ts:

```
import { Foo } from 'foo';
new Foo();
```

As far as I understand that should work, it doesn't and for it to work it is necessary to have the following (which I want to avoid):

```
import { Foo } from '../foo';
new Foo();
```

Comment: Did you have any luck with this?

Comment: @yafrack No :/ I think I will wait until ionic 2 final is released to continue with this, since I also opened this on the ionic forum and there isn't any reply either.

Comment: So you are just doing the long paths right now? If it's a bug it I don't know why it's not a priority. It makes big projects unscalable :(

Comment: Yes I am doing the long paths right now. Well seeing that someone else is interested in this I will continue to push it forward. Part of my decision to wait for this until the final release is that I got no response anywhere. I will update this question if I get any more updates :D.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34925992/how-to-avoid-imports-with-very-long-relative-paths-in-angular-2 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41310614/relative-paths-baseurl-and-paths-not-working-on-ionic2-angular2/41317368?noredirect=1#comment69838671_41317368 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34373642/angular-2-importing-module-without-having-to-traverse-e-g?rq=1

Comment: Yes seems like your question is basically the same problem that I have. Let's see if we can find a way to fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to override the default webpack.config.js to be able to resolve files relative to the `baseUrl`.

In order to use a custom webpack configuration file with ionic, this should be added to the package.json of the project:

```
{
    ...
    "config": { "ionic_webpack": "./webpack.config.js" },
    ...
}
```

And then in `./webpack.config.js`:

```js
var path = require('path');
var useDefaultConfig = require('@ionic/app-scripts/config/webpack.config.js');

// to match the basePath in tsconfig.json, we add src as a module path, which means we can use
// module style imports for our code. Without this, an import that typescript thinks is valid, like
// `import { Foo } from 'foo';` will fail at build time
useDefaultConfig.dev.resolve.modules.push(path.resolve('src'));
useDefaultConfig.prod.resolve.modules.push(path.resolve('src'));


/**
 * export the update ionic webpack configs (this still includes both dev & prod webpack configs)
 */
module.exports = function () {
  return useDefaultConfig;
};
```

Comment: As extra information, in order to use a custom webpack configuration file with ionic, this should be added to the package.json of the project:

    "config": {
        "ionic_webpack": "./webpack.config.js"
    }

Also, this answer does solve the question, but since I did the question a long time ago, I have already solved this problem with a different approach (which also involves using a custom webpack config). My current approach was taken from this: https://decembersoft.com/posts/say-goodbye-to-relative-paths-in-typescript-imports/

Comment: Thanks @NoelDeMartin, I forgot to mention that - edited the answer accordingly. Nice blogpost also!

Comment: I have been using Ionic 3 and after doing the above configuration, it's still not working.